# Creating modern team site takes long time to complete

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, office-365-groups, modern-team-site

I am creating modern team sites from managed code using PnP Unified Groups utility from PnP core with app-only permissions. This has been working just fine until recently.

Now, the SharePoint site has the status = Creating for a rather long time. E.g. 75 minutes. I check site status with this PnP cmdlet:

> Get-PnPTenantSite -Url [someurl] | FT Status

During that period modifications to the site fail with an exception like so:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Cannot set properties on
>   site [someurl] because the site is not currently available

Previously (before this error started to occur), the site could be modified even in the Creating state. Also, it typically took 2 to 5 minutes for the status to change to Active.

When status changes to Active everything works as expected. The issue appears on two tenants: a production tenant in EMEA and a MS demo tenant in US region.

Has anyone a work-around for this issue, except for waiting it out?

**UPDATE 2017-08-28**

As of today this is working much better than last week. Now, about 50 % of the sites are created as previously while the rest still has the issue.

**UPDATE 2017-08-30**

I have heard that others are experiencing the same problem. Percentage of 'slow' sites and time to completion varies quite a bit. A new thing I noticed yesterday is that sometimes the group creation does not return a SharePoint URL. After waiting a bit the SharePoint site will be created anyways.

**UPDATE 2017-08-31**

I have been creating about 1000 groups in a production tenant the recent days and noticed one more issue that might be related. In some cases, the site status changes immediately after group creation to Active. This is not really a good thing, because the site creation did not complete so fast. Changes applied to one of these site might fail for random reasons, e.g. Document library does not exist and the like.

**UPDATE 2017-09-01**

One more thing I noticed today. About 10 % of my groups are created without a SharePoint site. When asking for the SharePoint site (drive) via Graph API I receive this error message: Unable to provision resource. Even after waiting for some time (e.g. 24 hours or so) the SharePoint site is *NOT* provisioned. But, when migrating the group to a Microsoft Team, the SharePoint site is created finally.

**Update 2017-10-10**
Noticed a new issue today. When accessing a O365 Group after creation I am getting the following exception. Only work-around seems to delete the group and create it again

> Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' was thrown.: 
>   Code: ResourceNotFound  Message: Resource provisioning is in progress.
>   Please try again.

Comment: Do manually created team sites exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Good question, have not tried yet...

Comment: am facing same issue. have created around 90 modern team sites and only 11 was created. rest are in creating phase. so, any idea what to do next? i mean should i leave as such and it will be created after a day or two.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81525)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81525)

Comment: Raj - thanks for your comment! Best thing to do currently seems to be waiting. In my case it takes typically between 30 and 90 minutes until the sites change to Active... After that, the sites accept all programmatic modifications as expected.

Comment: My solution is to poll every five minutes until the site is there...that could in theory be weeks if no one touches the site (for that scenario). To me it's more an inconvenience as much as a problem. If the site is not 100% configured one a user hits it the first time...that is usually ok. And checking is not a problem as it's a workflow running. If you really need to work past it, hit the create api with a service account and pw.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MikaelSvenson - I agree it is not so much of a problem in most cases. The only thing that worries me a bit are the 10 % of groups (in my case) that fail to provision the SharePoint site (Unable to provision resource error message).

Comment: @BerndRickenberg but if a user access it via the UI, it is created. If no one ever enters the site, is it needed? :)

Comment: @MikaelSvenson, unfortunately not with this one. If you get the Unable to provision resource error accessing the site via UI does not help. You just get a 404. Only thing that helped me was to migrate the group to a team - than the SharePoint site was created eventually.

Comment: @BerndRickenberg wow, not seen that, and totally weird. I'll be testing lots of group prov these days so will look out for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this while creating groups through Graph and as an alternative, I use the New-PnPSite command from PnP Powershell to create a modern site (other way round). This also creates an Office 365 group in the background and works very well.

Yes, it takes a couple of minutes to provision the site fully in the background but it does get provisioned. If you want to apply a PnP template after provisioning the site consider having a delay of about 2-3 mins between the operations.